# Espaço entre divs

Tags: css, css3

Bom Dia!

Tenho a figura abaixo onde entre a figura "**GÁS A DOMICILIO**"  e a `Div` que contém uns **botões vermelhos**, vemos um **espaço**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O problema é que esse **espaço** não existe no **código**.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
}
div.banner {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
div.sessoes {
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
div.banner {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
div.banner img{
    width:100%;
}
```

index.php

```
<div class="banner">
   <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once "_requeridos/banner.php"; ?></div>
</div>
```

banner.php

```
<img src="_img/_banner/banner2.png"/>
```

Pode ser visto em: http://www.gasmuriae.com.br/

Como remover isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta no ficheiro de css colocar display: block na tag img da class banner:

```
div.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Mas aí surgiu uma dúvida: Olhando no inspector, a img está com 300px de altura, a div.sessoes com 308px de atura e a div.banner com 308px de altura devido à altura da div.sessoes. Isto é, se alterar no inspector a altura da div.sessoes para 300px manualmente, logo a div.banner se ajusta aos 300px automaticamente, o que me leva a acreditar que o problema, seja ele qual for, está na div sessoes e não na img. Não?

Comment: No inspector, na aba que mostra as medidas da imagem, não mostra nenhuma medida além do width e do hieght. Nada de border, margin ou outra medida. Tudo 0.

Comment: Essa resposta resolveu mas gostaria de saber porque resolveu se ocorrem as situações descritas no comentário anterior!